# Android: Change number format for the whole application?

Tags: android, localization

In Android we can change the applications locale like this:

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("ar","EG");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

and we can format the number to display digits according to a certaub locale like this:

```
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("ar","EG"));
nf.format(numberString);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to just change the locale for the number format for the whole application without changing the application's locale? in other words is there a way to set the application's locale to **"en-US"** while set the number format only to **"ar-EG"**? is that possible?

Comment: What's the problem with the code in your second snippet? There, you are changing the locale for the `NumberFormat`.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to do this for every TextView or EditText in the whole application, I'm wondering if there is a way to set the number format globally

Comment: "I'll have to do this for every TextView or EditText in the whole application" -- or, have a singleton `NumberFormat`. Or, if those are not thread safe, a global object pool of `NumberFormat` instances. The rest of your app gets a `NumberFormat` from the singleton or pool.

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution, I guess there is no other way to do this without the TextViews being aware of the singleton/pool of NumberFormat?

Comment: IMHO, widgets should not be aware of formatters. Your controller or presenter would be aware of formatters, or perhaps your layout resources if you are using something like the data binding framework.